# SSN Validation Issues

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 web application in which I am trying to validate SSN number using Jquery Mask Plugin But I want when I open the form in edit mode, then I should not able to complete SSN for example if my SSN is 123-45-6789 then in edit mode I should able to see XXX-XX-6789. I have used the masking for this purpose but when I put XXX-XX-6789 on the SSN in edit mode then it gives me error that alphabets are nit allowed in SSN, so plx suggest me the method to validate SSN and also to fulfill the requirement of edit mode. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: How about putting it as a password field ? It will mask the whole content and at the same time it should pass your validation.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can come up with off the top of my head is to add a line like this in the function that validates the SSN:

```
function validateSSN(ssnInput){
    if(ssnInput.value==ssn.defaultValue) return;

    //validate SSN
}
```

That conditional will only check the SSN in the event the user has changed it.